# @Input Parent Child component binding

Tags: angular

I am using [this](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/angular-7-share-component-data-with-other-components-1b91d6f0b93f) code to test out parent/child @Input decorator.

I expect to see "Example: Hello Angular 7" displayed on the child page, I only see "Example:"

This is the parent component file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child [childExample]="parentExample"></app-child>
  `
 })
export class ParentComponent{
parentExample: string = 'Hello Angular 7';
```

}

This is the child component code:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
      Example: {{ childExample }}
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() childExample: string;
}
```

This is the app.component.html component

```
<app-nav></app-nav><router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is my an abridged app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { ParentComponent } from './parent.component'
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CreditCardComponent,
    ParentComponent,
   ChildComponent   
  ],
  imports: [
   BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,


  ],
  providers: [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
  StripeComponent

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the app-routing.module

```
import { ParentComponent } from './parent.component'
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component'

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'stocks', component: StocksComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
{ path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent},
{ path: 'stripe',  component: StripeComponent},
{ path: 'cc',  component: CreditCardComponent},
{ path: 'parent',  component: ParentComponent},
{ path: 'child',  component: ChildComponent},
```

Comment: Do you have any error on the console of your browser?

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Comment: Which component are you using in your app.component.html file (or app.component.ts file if you have inline template)?

Comment: No console errors for either, child or parent.  I added the app.component.html file in the question

Comment: Can you add also your module file? and what url are you opening in browser?

Comment: Then you need to specify that you want for that particular url to load `ParentComponent`.

Comment: The code seems to be valid. I've copied it to stackblitz and it works as expected. See here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sblsov

Comment: Yes, it works there but you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your template which suggests that you use routing. If you don't use routing and just want to see the text on the screen, then replace it with `<app-nav></app-nav><app-parent></app-parent>` and it should work.

Comment: I will restart the application in vs code.  Did not change.  The child component does not match the parent as expected.  Thanks Sergey

Comment: I think you has been seeing "child" component, NOT "parent". Your router show localhost:4200/parent?

Comment: You are correct, I was seeing the child component.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Eliseo is correct.  I was not rendering the 'app-parent' element.  Once I did it worked.